# Deployment, multiple servers with env variables

Tags: laravel, deployment, environment-variables

I'm working on deploying an application (and preparing for future deployments with more servers).  Currently, the application runs on 4 servers, and there are Dev, Staging and Production Environments.  I've written a Python script to provision each server and setup a lot of what I need on each box.

However, I have a large file containing environmental variables (This is a Laravel app by the way) and I'm trying to figure out a way to incorporate it into the provisioning.

Im trying to avoid manually copying it to each server on every deployment.  Furthermore, if I need to add or modify an env variable in the future, I'd like to avoid manually trying to keep each copy in sync on each server.

However, I also don't want to commit it to github with the provisioning script.

Any suggestions to keep this process more DRY?  Whats the best practicing for handling environmental configurations for deployment to different environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a script to setup and provision each server, you can put the variables that go into Laravel's .env file anywhere where they will be available as environment variables. They do not need to be set only in the .env file. A few options that come to mind based on your workflow:

1. The vhost file. The vhost will make the environment variables available to apache and PHP. But this will not make them available to command line processes like Artisan.
2. The web user's bash profile: The environment variables for each environment can be declared in the bash profile (`.profile`, `.bashrc`) and will be available each time the server boots to all processes.
3. The Python script can simply generate the .env file automatically for each environment. The .env file is not in the repo and is only read by Laravel if it exists. This would probably be the DRYist approach - but would require a repository that stored all the env settings across all environments so it would be less secure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Having the Python script generate everything sounds enticing, but then the question of "where are these values that the script references, stored?"  Is there any sort of secure place to host them ? (Besides GitHub). I suppose I could store them on another one of my servers, and each server instance could scp them from there?  The other option could maybe be to remotely provision each server. So provision staging, from my local environment. This way, I could store all the sensitive info locally?

Comment: There is no secure answer to this problem. The most secure approach is the way you're trying to avoid which is to have a privileged user access their credentials from a "vault" and place an `.env` file in the environment with just the creds for that environment. This privileged user might not even be the developers themselves. Ideally the vault would only be accessible locally to the provisioning Python script and not open it to a network. All other options that require making credentials accessible to a network pose problems even with schemes like OAuth, TLS, and standing encryption imo.